# Grouping and binning data for feature engineering

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, binning

I struggle to divide my data into bins for feature engineering. The data is Sale Price that I want to group by categorical data (Neighbourhood).

What am i doing wrong - I got `NaN` values for all the rows? Thanks!

```py
    pricy_location = train['SalePrice'].groupby(train['Neighborhood']).mean()
    label = ['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5']
    train['Pricy_Loc'] = pd.qcut(pricy_location, 5, labels=label, precision=2)
    train['Pricy_Loc'].head()
```

Comment: Could you share with us a sample of your data, please?

Comment: Can you share your sample Input?

Comment: Data and more info about it is here, sorry for not adding it :) https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises because you are creating a dataframe grouped by neighborhood (which is only 25 rows long) and then trying to use the categories created for that dataframe and applying it to a much longer dataframe that is 1460 rows long. You can simply get the summarized data in a new column of your train dataframe and then bin the result:

```
train['Pricy_loc'] = train.groupby('Neighborhood')['SalePrice'].transform('mean')
label = ['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4', 'rank5']
train['Price_loc_cat'] = pd.qcut(train['Pricy_loc'], 5, labels=label, precision=2)
```

Comment: Yup that fixes the problem. Thank's a lot. In code there should be groupby(train['Neighborhood'])

Comment: Glad I could help. If you wouldn't mind, you could accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. :)